# Excel VBA: Searching a text and making it bold and change cell color

Tags: excel, vba

New to all this but appreciate any help I can get.

Problem: I have a duty roster with initials and sometimes I want to highlight a specific person to see his/her schedule. The highlight consists of changing the font color and making it bold but I'd also like the cell color to change as well, to lets say light green. I do know that I can use the Search/Replace feature but I'd like a macro for this.

So far, I've managed to piece together an input box and I can change the font color and add 'bold' to the font (and other changes) but I haven't solved changing the cell color.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub FindAndBold()
Dim sFind As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCount As Long
Dim iLen As Integer
Dim iFind As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange. _
  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There are no cells with text"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

sFind = InputBox( _
  Prompt:="Skriv in dina initialer", _
  Title:="Dina initialer")
If sFind = "" Then
    MsgBox "Du skrev inget"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

iLen = Len(sFind)
lCount = 0

For Each rCell In rng
    With rCell
        iFind = InStr(.Value, sFind)
        Do While iFind > 0
            .Characters(iFind, iLen).Font.Bold = True
            .Characters(iFind, iLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Characters(iFind, iLen).Font.ColorIndex = 4
            lCount = lCount + 1
            iStart = iFind + iLen
            iFind = InStr(iStart, .Value, sFind)
        Loop
    End With
Next

If lCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Fanns inget" & _
      vbCrLf & "' " & sFind & " '" & _
      vbCrLf & "att markera"
ElseIf lCount = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Det fanns en" & _
      vbCrLf & "' " & sFind & " '" & _
      vbCrLf & "markerades"
Else
    MsgBox lCount & " hittade" & _
      vbCrLf & "' " & sFind & " '" & _
      vbCrLf & "och markerades"
End If

ExitHandler:
Set rCell = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume ExitHandler
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
(The text in the prompt and response is in Swedish)

Comment: Have you considered using conditional formatting? Have a cell where you pick a particular employee and their name is highlighted?

Comment: `rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed` or `rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10`

Comment: @Solar Mike: No, I haven't. Problem is that sometimes there's more than one initial in one cell, so that solution isn't that ideál.

Comment: @Alex P: Where do you suggest I insert that?

Comment: Where you have `.Characters`. This is where you are doing the formatting and have the `rCell` object available.

Comment: Alex P: I'm probably doing something wrong. I put your line below the .Characters-lines and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using conditional formatting, no need for VBS. 
Using a conditional format formula you can enter something like this: `=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1;A2));$G$1<>"")` - in this case field G1 would be the field used for searching (read:highlighting) all the fields containing this condition.

If you desire a VBS we can improve and include a filter for all lines matching your search:

```
Sub searchfilter()
    Range("A11:M10000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("A2:M13"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

And to clear:

```
Sub clearfilter()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Assign both macros to a button.

Sample image where i combined both (filter was done on C15 in this case):
[image: sample usage]

And sample with hidden fields shown:
[image: sample with hidden fields]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite the solution I'm looking for. This sort of manipulates the whole worksheet and some lines become jumbled.